# How can I find the largest value in a row and return a certain value based on which cell it is?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to find the largest number in the "PAID" column in a row and return an indicator based on which cell it comes from to find who has the highest number of paid records. I also want it to list both indicators if there is a tie. How could I go about this?

Comment: Use `MAXIFS()` function. What would be your desired output from given dataset?

Comment: @Harun24hr It would be based on the letter in the header at the start of each color. i.e., SB, N, T, D, or R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option you could adapt to fit your specific needs:

[image]

Formula in `A9`:

```
=LET(y,TAKE(WRAPROWS(A1:T1,4),,1),TEXTAFTER("|"&TEXTBEFORE(BYROW(A2:T6,LAMBDA(r,LET(x,INDEX(WRAPROWS(r,4),0,3),TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTER(y,x=MAX(x)))&REPT("|",ROWS(y))))),"|",SEQUENCE(,ROWS(y))),"|",-1))
```

Comment: @ jvdV after this, i simply concatenated the cells into one so i could have it all in one cell. thank you kindly. one more question! is there any way to have something come up if they are all 0's across the row? so it isnt just putting the leftmost column?