# How to enter an array, consisting of different arrays, as an input parameter for the "Match()" function?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, concatenation, input-parameters

I was trying to answer [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453242), when I realised that I don't know how to enter an array, consisting of different arrays, as an input parameter for the `INDEX()` or the `MATCH()` function.

Background:
As some of you know, you can find a value somewhere in an Excel sheet, and use the `INDEX(MATCH(...))` trick in order to find adjacent cells.

Simple example:

| Id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 5 |

The "Id", corresponding with the maximal value, can be found as:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(B2:B3,MATCH(MAX(B2:B3),B2:B3)),,-1)
```

This is relatively easy, but when the lookup array is spread over multiple columns, this seems not to work:

| Id | Value | Rubbish | Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | x | c | 2 |
| b | 5 | x | d | 7 |

The lookup array is no longer `B2:B3`, but `B2:B3,E2:E3`.
That lookup array can be used for the `MAX()` function, but when filling in this into the `INDEX()` and the `MATCH()` function, Excel seems to think that I'm filling in two input parameters, `B2:B3` and `E2:E3` (because of the comma in between).

So I need a function, let's call it `TREAT_AS_ONE_ARRAY()`, so that I can use my formula:

```
=OFFSET(
   INDEX(
     TREAT_AS_ONE_ARRAY(B2:B3,E2:E3),
     MATCH(MAX(B2:B3,E2:E3),
           TREAT_AS_ONE_ARRAY(B2:B3,E2:E3)
          )
   ),,-1)
```

Does such a function exist?

Comment: I don't think such a syntax exists. But your current sample data would allow for something like `=TOCOL(IF(B2:E3=MAX(B2:E3),A2:D3,NA()),3)`, thus applying all sorts of new dynamic array functions to reshape an array. Ultimately, I don't think this was what you tried to achieve with this question?

Comment: JvdV's set-up is obviously preferable, though theoretically speaking `FREQUENCY(MAX(B2:B3,E2:E3),(B2:B3,E2:E3))` will give you a 1-dimensional array you can then manipulate as befits your needs.

Comment: @JvdV: No, I was just looking for a way to use the `INDEX(MATCH())` trick, without actually altering the structure of the data. But as you state, this most probably does not exist. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I don't think that function you mean exists naturally in Excel. You could resolve it with different functions but I guess you are not looking for an answer like that. What you want is your `TREAT_AS_ONE_ARRAY` function

Comment: If only Excel would allow GS syntax, since it's perfectly possible over there.

Comment: do you mean `Index(VSTACK(array1,array2),xmatch(max(array1,array2,vstack(array1,array2)))` ?

Comment: I used the choose() function to control the contents of one range based on selecting between 6 choices - this was to translate between languages.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes", with Office 365 you can use **VSTACK** to "treat as one array". Before we get to that, though, let's clear up a few things...

First, your use of OFFSET with INDEX and MATCH is unnecessary. The *array* parameter in the INDEX function should be treated as the *return_array*, which can be different than the *lookup_array* used in the MATCH function.

Second, the optional *[match_type]* parameter in the MATCH function should be set to **0** (exact match) to ensure the first match is returned. If omitted, the default setting is **1** (Less than), which may appear to work at first glance, but can produce unexpected results if the *lookup_array* is not sorted in ascending order, or if multiple matches are present.

As such, the following formula would be more appropriate for your first "simple example" shown above:

```
=INDEX(A2:A3, MATCH(MAX(B2:B3), B2:B3, 0))
```

Third, the MATCH function will only accept a one-dimensional array (either vertical or horizontal), whereas the INDEX function is perfectly capable of accepting two-dimensional arrays. Furthermore, INDEX will also accept range references consisting of multiple areas, when utilizing the secondary syntax:

```
=INDEX(reference, row_num, [column_num], [area_num])
```

To use a range reference with multiple areas, it must be enclosed in brackets. For example:

```
=INDEX((A2:A3, D2:D3), row_num, [column_num], [area_num])
```

The optional *[area_num]* parameter determines which area is returned from the *reference*. In the above example, **1** would return the corresponding value from `A2:A3` and **2** would return the corresponding value from `D2:D3`.

Lastly, although the MATCH function will only accept a one-dimensional array, it's perfectly capable of handling multiple criteria across multiple columns. The generic formula structure for this is as follows:

```
// using multiple AND conditions:
=MATCH(1, (range1=value1)*(range2=value2), 0)

// using multiple OR conditions:
=MATCH(1, --(((range1=value1)+(range2=value2))>0), 0)
```

With these concepts in mind, you can definitely achieve something close to the desired outcome strictly by using combinations of INDEX and MATCH.

**Sample Data:**

| Id | Value | Rubbish | Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | x | d | 2 |
| b | 5 | y | e | 7 |
| c | 7 | z | f | 3 |

For simplicity, we'll break the process down into steps:

**(1)** In cell `B7`, return the maximum of the two "Value" columns shown in the sample data above:

```
=MAX(B2:B4, E2:E4)
```

**(2)** In cell `B8`, return the row number of the first match found in either the first "Value" column OR the second "Value" column where the value is equal to the maximum value:

```
=MATCH(1, --(((B2:B4=B7)+(E2:E4=B7))>0), 0)
```

**(3)** In cell `B9`, return the area number where the first match was found:

```
=MATCH(B7, INDEX((B2:B4, E2:E4), B8, , {1,2}), 0)
```

**(4)** In cell `B10`, return the corresponding value from the "Id" column:

```
=INDEX((A2:A4, D2:D4), B8, , B9)
```

**Results:**

[image: index_match_reference.png]

**Note:** with older versions of Excel, be sure to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter in steps 2 to 4 above.

With Office 365, this method can also be simplified with the LET function:

```
=LET(
maxVal, MAX(B2:B4, E2:E4),
rowNum, MATCH(1, --(((B2:B4=maxVal)+(E2:E4=maxVal))>0), 0),
areaNum, MATCH(maxVal, INDEX((B2:B4, E2:E4), rowNum, , {1,2}), 0),
INDEX((A2:A4, D2:D4), rowNum, , areaNum))
```

As stated at the beginning of this answer, though, if you have Office 365, **VSTACK** can be used as a direct solution to your question:

```
=INDEX(VSTACK(A2:A4, D2:D4),
   MATCH(MAX(B2:B4, E2:E4), VSTACK(B2:B4, E2:E4), 0))
```

**VSTACK Results:**

[image: index_match_vstack.png]

As you can see, it's entirely possible for these two methods to produce two different results when multiple matches are present; however, BOTH results are correct. The multi-area range reference method returns the first match found (`E3=7`) when searching across *both* "Value" columns together, whereas the VSTACK method returns the first match found (`B4=7`) by first searching the entire *first* "Value" column, followed by the entire *second* "Value" column.